Why isn’t Cypress referred to as “Cypress WebDriver” like “Selenium WebDriver”?
I’ve been working with both Selenium and Cypress for automated testing and I understand that WebDriver is used in both. However, I noticed that we often refer to “Selenium WebDriver,” but not “Cypress WebDriver.” Can anyone explain why Cypress isn’t typically referred to as “Cypress WebDriver” in the same way? Is there a specific reason for this difference in terminology?

No, Cypress does not use WebDriver. It has its own implementation to 'drive' the browser.

Does Cypress use Selenium / Webdriver? No. In fact Cypress'
architecture is very different from Selenium in a few critical ways:
https://docs.cypress.io/faq/questions/general-questions-faq#Does-Cypress-use-Selenium--Webdriver


Agreed. The creators of Cypress have some very strong opinions against Selenium WebDriver
